# Looking to obtain the Interbase ODS number programmatically

Tags: interbase

We are spread over a few versions of the ODS from 15 through 17.
Really, we are rolling out with XE7 which is version 16.

Does anyone know how to read the ODS number from a local database to identify that an update is required?

John

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what programming interface/connectivity you are using in your application to get to InterBase.

InterBase API has a isc_database_info() function to get information about various properties. You are looking for isc_info_ods_version property value. In your InterBase examples/ folder, there is a sample, dbinfo.c. This shows you how to use the C api to get this value.

If you are using InterBase Express (IBX) components via Delphi/C++Builder, you can use IBDatabaseInfo component to get the information. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/IBX.IBDatabaseInfo.TIBDatabaseInfo.ODSMajorVersion

If you are using FireDAC to connect to InterBase, you can use the following. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Phys.IBWrapper.TIBDatabase.ods_version